# Get entire row when group an ID in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Im trying to select the entire row that has the heighest value in points. When Im trying to GROUP it turns out that I cant select entire row. So I came up with this query down here.

```
SELECT i1.*
FROM objects i1
LEFT OUTER JOIN objects i2
  ON (i1.product = i2.product AND i1.points < i2.points)
WHERE i2.product IS NULL and i1.product < $day
order by product asc, points desc
```

The table:

```
product   name      points   message
----------------------------------------
1         Joe       4        Message 1
2         Steve     15       Message 2
2         Loui      17       Message 3
3         Larry     10       Message 4
3         Harry     10       Message 5
3         Hank      8        Message 6
```

I want result like this:

```
product   name      points   message
----------------------------------------
1         Joe       4        Message 1
2         Loui      17       Message 3
3         Larry     10       Message 4
```

Now, product will be returned twice if two rows have the same points.

How can I select so I only got one row for each product with the highest points?

Comment: in output why thers larry there can be harry too right ?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
SELECT i1.*
FROM objects i1
where points= (select max(points) from objects i2 where i1.product=i2.product)
```

and sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4caa0/1

Comment: Nested query like this one is more straightforward and more intuitive but less effective, I think.

Comment: I completely agree with you, however I am not quite advanced in MySQL. If the question was MS SQL Server, I would try a different approach such as windowed function: `ROW_NUMBER over (partition by product order by points DESC) as seq` and then specify `seq=1`

Comment: This also returns several rows with the same product id

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATED

With MySQL variables, you can accomplish what you want. (but, not sure this is good way in practice) you can test here. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7fe7/4/0

```
SET @prev := 0; -- Initialize

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT IF(@prev = o.product, 0, 1) just_one, @prev:=o.product,
        o.product, o.name, o.message, x.m_p
    FROM (
        SELECT product, MAX(points) m_p
        FROM objects
        GROUP BY product
    ) x INNER JOIN objects o ON x.product = o.product AND x.m_p = o.points
    ORDER BY o.product
) z
WHERE
    just_one = 1;
```

Assuming `UNIQUE(product, name)`.

### Orig. Answer

could you try this?

```
SELECT o.product, o.name, o.message, x.m_p
FROM (
    SELECT product, MAX(points) m_p
    FROM objects
    GROUP BY product
) x INNER JOIN objects o ON x.product = o.product AND x.m_p = o.points
```

Comment: aha... just one product should be printed when more than two rows have same points... wait a minute

Comment: This return several rows with same points.

Comment: @LersGoRangers could you give me more sample data at sqlfiddle for ease of test? Data in your question is above sqlfiddle. It seems that my query working.

Comment: @LetsGoRangers I Have inserted more duplicated value. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d416f0/1/0 could you post more data here?

Comment: OK, this code does not work in my database. This code in the sqlfiddle URL return 7 rows.  What can be wrong? This is my server: 

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server version: 5.5.34-32.0-log
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: @LetsGoRangers Very weird... I'll think about it after work.

Comment: Yes, very wierd :/ It works on sqlfiddle but the same work show duplicates in my database.

Comment: @LetsGoRangers oops, I can't write _AT_ at comment. could you try "SET _AT_prev := 0;"

Comment: @LetsGoRangers Replace "_AT_" to 'Shift + 2'

Comment: @LetsGoRangers I also using MySQL 5.5.32, utf8.